# List and count markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need to count and list the markers that are within a figure either a sirculo or a rectangle.

The operation would be that when you insert a figure on the map I list and count how many markers inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Circle and Rectangle classes have a getBounds() function, which returns a LatLngBounds object.  Add your circle/rectangle and get its bounds.  Loop over your markers, calling the contains() function on each marker to see if it is contained in that latlng bounds.

You may need to be slightly cleverer with the circle, as its bounds will be for the bounding box that surrounds it, so you might have markers that fall outside the circle but still within that box.  In which case you'd need to work something out based on the radius of the circle.